# JSP - session is undefined?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session

I'm trying to pass a variable between two jsp files, but when I come to use them, I get an error saying that 'session is undefined'

I'm using the following:

```
Jsp1:
//following function is called on a button press
function clickAndClose()
{
    session.setAttribute("test", "some value here");

    window.close(); 
}

Jsp2:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Show Selected RS Number
    <script language="javascript">
        String number = session.getAttribute("test");
        session.removeAttribute("test");
        document.write(number);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The fact I get an error on session.setAttribute confuses me, as I thought session was an implicit object (included?) ?

Note: I'm getting an error on `session.setAttribute("test", "some value");` , saying that session is undefined, NOT `String text = session.getAttribute("test");`

Comment: `session` is indeed an implicit object. Better to show some code to find out what is going on...

Comment: Tom Can you please show the jsp

Comment: if my memory doesn't betray me, the complete signature is Object getAttribute(String name), shouldn't you need a cast there?

Comment: See updated question :)

Comment: I'm still missing something, the code you add seems a mix of java and javascript. Are you sure you're not mixing client side and server side worlds? AFAIK there's no direct way to access Session from javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `session` inside `<script language="javascript">` tag, it is not available there. Use it inside `scriptlet` or `jstl` tags.

> Javascript is executed in client side, whereas jsp implicit objects are available and executed in server side

Comment: Ah, I think this is where I'm gettting confused! Thanks for helping, just picking up the language so still working out the kinks! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can't access directly the session in javascript, thou you can trick it with something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Show Selected RS Number
    <script language="javascript">
        var number = '<%= session.getAttribute("test") %>';
        document.write(number);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
 sess.setAttribute("test", "some value");%>
```

the above code will give you the session object which is required. Use of EL (expression language) and JSTL tags is highly recommended. For example, here you could use EL as

```
<td><input type="text" value="${test}" /></td>
```

Comment: first `session` is an implicit object. so no need of creating it again.